# Getting element using withName of Number in UIAElementArray

Tags: javascript, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to get to a element (using javascript) which is inside UIAElementArray that has a number name like 1.

So when I try to get the element say with 
array()["1"]

I am still getting the element at the index 1, instead of element which has a name/key value of 1.

Before some of you shoo me off to [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementArrayClassReference/Introduction/Introduction.html), I found this and tried using firstWithName and withName 
array().firstWithName("1")
but now I am getting a weird error **"-[__NSCFNumber    length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c81ab0"**

I haven't used length explicitly anywhere, what does the error mean and how do I get out of this?

Comment: What is the `array()` function you are calling? It sounds like you're trying to call `firstWithName()` on something that's not a UIAElementArray. Can you provide a code snippet for more context?

Comment: Array above is mainWindow().popover().staticTexts()

Comment: I don't know what happened before but firstWithName works now. I discovered withName("1")[0] also works.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly regarding the error but I know how to get required element. Try this one:

```
var predicate = "name contains '1'";
var requiredObj = mainWindow().popover().staticTexts().firstWithPredicate(predicate);
```

Hope this will help.